# how to sign in for vscode extension github pull requests

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I installed the extension of github pull requests and did not find the sign in window popped up. I have restarted the vscode and nothing happened. 
I also tried to search "github pull requests: sign in " and still nothing.

[image]

How can I sign in for this extension?

---

I am using Ubuntu 18

Comment: Do you see a GitHub icon in the activity bar (the bar on the far left of VS Code)? Did you try opening a repo that is connected to GitHub?

Comment: Try cloning the repo locally and opening it in VS Code. The extension should automatically detect GitHub repository you open

Comment: @AlexF You should probably open your own question / issue for that